# Returning subset of properties from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, subset, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like

```
var array = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}]
```

I am trying to get a subset of the object properties like var

```
var newArray = [['01/01/2017',200],['01/01/2017',200],['01/01/2017',200]......]
```

I do not want an array like this

```
[[date:'',value2:],[date:'',value2:],[date:'',value13:]]
```

But just directly a 2 D array from array of objects.

Currently I am doing a for each on my array of objects and pushing the required properties in to an array an returning that array.

I was looking for map function may be if that can work but this does not work with map

```
array.map(function(item){ 
return {
      item.date, item.value1
       }
});
```

Kindly suggest if there is any other function to do this without looping over?

Thanks

Comment: just fix your syntax error on the array literal you're done.

Comment: Yup that was the mistake :)

Answer (score 5):

You should use `map` for this, you were almost there. This will sort you out:

```
array.map(function(item){ return [item.date,item.value1]});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked bu for some reason i was getting 'undefined' the second property. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the values in an array & `map` method will do rest of the work

```js
var array = [{
  date: '01/01/2017',
  value1: 200,
  value2: 300,
  value3: 400
}, {
  date: '01/01/3017',
  value1: 500,
  value2: 300,
  value3: 400
}];
var m = array.map(function(item) {
  return [item.date, item.value1]
})

console.log(m)
```

```html
[['01/01/2017',200],['01/01/2017',200]]
```